# Android can't access Windows SMB shared USB drives

Tags: windows-7, usb, android, samba

Windows shared SMB USB disk drives are accessible by Windows 7 machines on the network but not by Android devices.  Shared internal drives are accessible but if the drive is an external USB drive with the same permissions then none of the various Android SMB access applications can see it.  What must I do to fix that or is it an Android SMB client bug?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Registry key approach did not work on my Windows 10 Professional, but PowerShell command `Set-SmbServerConfiguration -IRPStackSize` does.

Before issuing the `Set-` command I ran `Get-SmbServerConfiguration` to check the current values. It returned **15** although the registry value was **40**!

Then I used `Set-SmbServerConfiguration -IRPStackSize 40`, restarted the **Server** service, and it all worked fine.

I highly recommend that you always restart the **Server** service after changing these values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (all SMB clients but those in an Android having access to particular shared location in a Windows machine even though I entered the same logon credentials to all clients).

For me, the fix was:

1. Log into the Windows machine.
2. Start registry (regedit) as an administrator.
3. Click your way to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters

4. In the right panel, see that item "EnableAuthenticateUserSharing" has the value of 0.
5. Double-click the item and change the value to 1.
6. Click "OK" to close.
7. No need to restart the Windows machine.

If in step 4, you already see the value 1, this obviously cannot be your fix.  Also, you may have multiple issues, and this alone may not suffice.

ADDED LATER

The above fix worked only for a few days, and I found the old problem again.  SMB working except with Android as client and a particular Windows machine as server (Android machines could SMB to other Windows machines).

What then worked was to "Force stop" the Android client app and restarting it.

See this for more:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127376/logon-failure-with-es-file-explorer-and-windows-lan

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here in the third post (with help, of course from Google):

https://community.wd.com/t/wd-tv-live-does-not-see-shared-windows-usb-drives-that-are-connected-via-hub/83248/3

In brief, the machine hosting the USB drives must have a registry entry called IRPStackSize.  The link gives the details.  I tried it and now I can access all that machines drives from Android via SMB.

Comment: +1.  This actually led me to a fix.